# How does host machine's CPU utilized by docker containers and other applications running on host?

Tags: docker, jmeter, cpu-usage

I am running a micro-service application in docker container and have to test that using JMeter tool. So I am running JMeter on my host machine and my host machine has 4 cores. I allocate 2 cores to the container using --cpu=2 flag while running the container. so it means it can use up to 2 cores as per it needs while running. I leave the remaining 2 cores for the JMeter and other applications and system usage.

Here I need a clarification that what will happen if JMeter and other application needs more than 2 cores and container also needs allocated 2 cores fully ?
Is there any way to allocate 2 cores fully to the container? (It means any other applications or system can't use that 2 cores)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is most probably "no", the explanations will differ depending on your operating system.

You can try to implement this by playing with [CPU affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity), however CPU is not only one metric you should be looking at, I would rather be concerned about RAM and Disk usage.

In general having load generator and application under test on the same physical machine is a very bad idea because they are both very resource intensive so consider using 2 separate machines for this otherwise both will suffer from [context switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) and you will not be able to monitor resources usage of JMeter and the application under test using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)